# RNN and TIme Series Forecasting using R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, recurrent-neural-network

I am currently working on time series project, I have tried SARIMA and Feed Forward neural networks for forecasting.
I found RNN(Recurrent Neural Network) as an interesting approach but am not finding any resources to understand RNN with implementation in R. 
Does anyone have some examples of RNN and forecasting in R?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May you should search for ltsm.

In R, you have here some exemples :
https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/blog/time-series-forecasting-with-recurrent-neural-networks.html

And perhaps thiscould be useful, Keras for R :
https://keras.rstudio.com/index.html